# How can I save a OpenCV histogram to a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'd like to save a calculated histogram from a file so that I can reopen it without having to recompute it, but I'm not sure how I would go about saving and then reading it again.

```
image_path = "/Users/..../test.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)
if image is not None: 
    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    cv2.imwrite("/Users/.../hist.jpg", hist) # What should this be?

hist = cv2.imread("/Users/.../hist.jpg", 0) # And this?
```

EDIT: 
So I'd like to do something like this, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

```
with open('hist.txt', 'a') as fp:
    fp.write('%s %s %s', [hist_id, list(hist), color])
with open('hist.txt', 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines: 
        hist_id = line[0]
        hist = np.array(eval(line[1]))
        color = line[2]
        cv2.compare(hist.....)
```

EDIT 2:

```
new_entry = [image, list(hist1), list(hist2)]
for item in new_entry:
    fd.write("%s\t" % item)
fd.write("\n")

with open('hist.txt', 'r') as fd:
     lines = fd.readlines()
     for line in lines:
         line = line.split('\t')
         cv2.compareHist(numpy.array(line[1]), numpy.array(line[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `cv2.calcHist` returns a 1D array, not an image, so you cannot save it with `cv2.imwrite`, but rather use a standard data file, such as CSV (comma separated values) for instance. If it's OK for you to store only one histogram per file, the easiest solution is to use a simple text file:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0,256])

with open('histo.txt', 'w') as file:
   file.write(list(hist))  # save 'hist' as a list string in a text file
```

then later:

```
with open('histo.txt', 'r') as file:
   hist = np.array(eval(file.read()) # read list string and convert to array
```

On the other hand, if your goal is not to **save** but to **plot** the histogram, matplotlib may be the easiest tool for that. This code snippet plots all three histograms for the R, G and B channels of your image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
colors = ('b','g','r')
for n, color in enumerate(colors):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [n], None, [256], [0,256])
    plt.plot(hist, color=color)
    plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm just looking to save the histogram so that I can make future comparisons using `cv2.compareHist()` without having to recalculate the histogram.

Comment: OK, so I edit the answer to include save/restore features for the histogram data

Comment: How would I write multiple per line (e.g. I want to associate an id with the histogram data). `file.write((hist_id, list(hist))`? and then `lines = file.readlines(); for line in lines: id = line[0]; hist = np.array(eval(line[1]));`

Comment: I edited my main post with how I write and read the lines, but I'm getting an error when I try to compare the histogram: `TypeError: H1 data type = 18 is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you wish to save the figure, `matplotlib` is a good way to do it. `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(‘my_cv2hist.png’)` would work for you, if it is to save the histogram as an image that you are looking for.

`imread` will just work fine if you are trying to read it back as the way you are trying to do it in your example code.

Comment: I'm just looking to save the histogram so that I can make future comparisons using `cv2.compareHist()` without having to recalculate the histogram.